# Ref react on select and option how to use

Tags: reactjs

What needs to be done so that when an option is selected, it is stored in ref?

```
<select className={style.formInput} ref={selectRef}>
                    {category.map((item) => <option value={item.name}
                                                    key={Math.random().toString()}>{item.name}</option>)}
</select>
```

Comment: Why do you want to store it in ref?

Comment: You are better off having no key at all than using a random number.  The key needs to stay the same across re-renders.

Comment: I have to double check but I think you can access the selected option with selectRef.current?.selected.

Comment: @ Ahmed Abdulrahman, I am displaying a dynamic list in select
each name from the list of options
I change one name to another, but it does not change, but in the state it is saved (I tried to do it through onChange)

Comment: @ Linda Paiste, no :(

Comment: Ok I looked it up the property name is [.selectedOptions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions) and it returns an HTMLCollection of selected option elements.  But that is not the right way to handle a select.  Using onChange and value to create a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag) is the right way.

Comment: @Linda Paiste, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
  export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({ category: "" });

  const formValue = (event) => {
    setState({ ...state, [event.target.name]: event.target.value.trim() });
  };

  const category = React.useRef(null);

  console.log("state", state);

  // On first render
  console.log("Category Ref", category.current && category.current.value);

  return (
    <div>
      <label>Categories</label>
      <select
        ref={category}
        onChange={formValue}
        name="category"
        value={state.category}
      >
        <option>Select a choice</option>
        <option value="First Choice">First Choice</option>
        <option value="Second Choice">Second Choice</option>
        <option value="Third Choice">Third Choice</option>
        <option value="Fourth Choice">Fourth Choice</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This way you can have it on state and access it on ref.